# Linear programming

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a function `f[x_]:= 3*(x - Pi/2)*(Sin[4*x])^2 + 2*Cos[3*x]`, and I need to use `LinearProgramming` command to find coefficients `c1, c2, c3` and `c4` of a function `g[x_]:= c1*Sin[2x] + c2*Sin[4x] + c3*Cos[x] + c4*Cos[3x]`, so that the maximum absolute error is minimized -> `min (max Abs[f[x] - g[x]])`, range `x` is from `0` to `Pi`.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: Why was this reposted?

Comment: No one answered me, and I have no idea how to do this. A suggestion was that I try FindFit, but that's not it.

Comment: Do you maybe know how to solve this with LinearProgramming?

Comment: Not offhand. But I think the Remez method does something with LP, minimizing maximal differences at Chebyshev node points. Or something along those lines.